# Partitioning Help Needed for Azure SQL

Tags: partitioning, azure-sql-database

Myself and some peers had some discussion about the approach for an issue regarding the care and feeding of a very large table in a Azure SQL database.
I understand that the main issue they are trying to address is performance of the data in the table. The solution that they have come up with was as follows:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.partition_functions WHERE name = 'PF_ExampleArchive_SubmissionDateDate')  
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [PF_ExampleArchive_SubmissionDateDate](DATE) AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES 
(
'2018-03-31', '2018-06-30', '2018-09-30', '2018-12-31',

'2019-03-31', '2019-06-30', '2019-09-30', '2019-12-31',

'2020-03-31', '2020-06-30', '2020-09-30', '2020-12-31',

'2021-03-31', '2021-06-30', '2021-09-30', '2021-12-31',

'2022-03-31', '2022-06-30', '2022-09-30', '2022-12-31',

'2023-03-31', '2023-06-30', '2023-09-30', '2023-12-31',

'2024-03-31', '2024-06-30', '2024-09-30', '2024-12-31',

'2025-03-31', '2025-06-30', '2025-09-30', '2025-12-31',

'2026-03-31', '2026-06-30', '2026-09-30', '2026-12-31',

'2027-03-31', '2027-06-30', '2027-09-30', '2027-12-31',

'2028-03-31', '2028-06-30', '2028-09-30', '2028-12-31',

'2029-03-31', '2029-06-30', '2029-09-30', '2029-12-31',

'2030-03-31', '2030-06-30', '2030-09-30', '2030-12-31',

'2040-12-31'
)
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.partition_schemes WHERE name = 'PS_ExampleArchive_SubmissionDateDate')  
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [PS_ExampleArchive_SubmissionDateDate] AS PARTITION [PF_ExampleArchive_SubmissionDateDate] ALL TO ([PRIMARY])
GO
```

- Create an Archive table with Partitions quarterly on a date field called SubmissionDate.
- Develop a procedure that inserts data into the archive table and deletes from the primary table weekly

When I was asked to do a review of the changes I mentioned the following:

- It looked to me that table partitions are set up only for the archive
  table rather that setting up for the archive table and the primary
  table. As I understand it, if both tables are using table partitions
  then moving data from primary to archive should not be a matter of
  inserting and deleting records which will cause locks for a longer
  period of time, fragmentation, etc but instead moving the data is a
  simple matter of updating which table the partition is located.
  Archiving data then becomes an operation that takes seconds rather
  than hours/days. My thought is that the complexity that partitions
  require overhead causes is not worth it for performance alone (and
  sometimes hampers performance). Their concern was that they would
  either need to change to monthly partitioning or if quarterly that an
  extra 90 days of data is a concern; I did not think the extra 90 days
  in the primary table to be a concern as a properly indexed table
  shouldn't have any issues. I also thought that since this is for an
  Azure SQL instance, the concern to get into the nitty gritty of the
  table design isn't required as much due to encapsulation of database
  processes if we are not going to be able to take advantage of the
  partitions in moving data around and purging of data.
- Not defining at what point to purge data from archive could lead to
  extra storage issues in the future. It was indicated that they expect
  the table to grow over 100 million records in a year and as it gets
  used more that the rate of growth will increase. They indicated they
  wanted to be proactive about this but I didn't see this step being
  proactive if only done on the archive table without any purge policy
  established.
- I didn't like the fact that the maintenance of the partitions were
  pretty much hard-coded rather than having some process that
  dynamically builds the partitions as needed as well as possibly
  having some sort of alert when data doesn't fall into current
  partition schemes.
- My final recommendation was to either implement table partitioning on
  both the primary and archive along with more robust maintenance of
  the partitioning or not do table partitioning at all

Would it be possible to primarily get some suggestions/information about best practices that help with going with the solution as provided or the feedback I provided? Secondarily, is there some code examples that can help in setting up ways to maintain the partition scheme as well as recommended alerts?
I am not sure if DBA Stack Exchange is a proper avenue for getting answers to this; If there is a better forum I should post, I would greatly appreciate letting me know.